# Come why not go?

Tags: bo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wording in Torah when Moshe is commanded to appear before pharoh](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/25612/wording-in-torah-when-moshe-is-commanded-to-appear-before-pharoh)

Why does it say בא to Pharaoh versus  לך to Pharaoh?