Numerology in the Plagues
Going over the plagues in Exodus, I notice a pattern. The first few plagues (blood, frogs, gnats / lice), are general afflictions that affect Egyptian and Hebrew alike. The next few plagues (flies, livestock, boils) affect everyone except the Hebrews - drawing a distinction between Egypt and God’s People. Then with the seventh plague (hail), this plague again only effected areas outside of Goshen (where the Hebrews live) BUT with the addition that those who believe God and do as instructed maybe spared (taking shelter along with one’s servants and animals).
The final three plagues repeat this pattern: the plague of locusts is a general affliction, the plague of darkness only effects the Egyptians - setting the Hebrews apart, and the final plague of the death of the firstborns is a general affliction BUT with an escape for those who believe God and act as instructed (blood of the Passover lamb).
Of course, there is one major distinction between the 7th and 10th plagues: in the 7th plague the Egyptians are informed how to be saved, while in the 10th this knowledge is only shared with the Hebrews by Moses (though there doesn’t appear to be any restriction from the Hebrews sharing this knowledge if they so chose with select Egyptians). Also - hypothetically Hebrews could have been afflicted as well. However, uncharacteristically, all of them obeyed this one time so that none were lost.
Fittingly, there is a nice division between the first 7 plagues and the final 3 within the narrative. After the 7th plague, Pharaoh finally admits that he has sinned (“this time”) and asks for Moses to intercede for him and agrees to let the Hebrews go. A big turn around from the start of the narrative where he claims to not know the LORD and therefore would not let the people go!
However, the LORD is not finished with them and so he hardens the hearts of Pharaoh and his officials that he might carry out the remaining judgements against Egypt.
Now, I know that 3, 7, and 10 are all significant numerals in scripture- but I haven’t studied numerology much myself. But I’m wondering what - if any - significance there is in there being 10 plagues broken into sets of 7 and 3.
Or, again, any potential significance in the first seven plagues being divided into sets of 3, 3, and 1.
Any insights? :)

See for instance https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/52523/21

Without getting into a big discussion, the 10 plagues correspond to the general structure of Creation in the Torah, namely the 10 Sefirot. They are divided into the 7 (emotional temperaments) Middot associated with the human torso, and the 3 (Intellectual aspects) Mochin or "Brains". What separates them is the point of constriction between head & torso, meaning the neck. Neck is Hebrew is עורף, which through letter rearrangement is related to Pharaoh spelled פרעה. Ideally, intellect directs the emotions. The neck resists that influence resulting in impulsive & thoughtless action.

@YaacovDeane that sounds intriguing  Any good English references that will let me dive deeper? :)

I would have to think about it. If you try looking at what are called Sichos in English at Kehotonline.com, you might find the Pharaoh/neck discussion connected with talks around Passover. For a good overview on the subject of the Sefirot, in the back of the Hebrew/English Tanya there is a good introduction.
